# How can I use myprovider in service in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I just referent the translateProvider in like this:

```js
    var myAppModule = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'ngResource', 'pascalprecht.translate']);
```

start js, and I want to use that in my commonService.js ,
like this:

```js
myAppModule.factory('commonService', ['$resource', '$translate', function ($resource, $translate) {
        var auth = $resource('http://localhost:8012/user/auth.aspx', {}, {});
        return {
            init: function () {
                var language = $resource("/Resources/Chinese.json");
                language.get(function (data) {
                    console.data(data);
                });
                $translate.translations('en', {
                    HEADLINE: 'Hello there, This is my awesome app!',
                    INTRO_TEXT: 'And it has i18n support!'
                })
             .translations('de', {
                 HEADLINE: 'Hey, das ist meine großartige App!',
                 INTRO_TEXT: 'Und sie untersützt mehrere Sprachen!'
             });
                $translate.preferredLanguage('de');
            },
            submit: function (user) {
                user.uk = "ad82544450d6fd3296878cbcd7a95d6b";
                return auth.get(user);
            }
        }
    }]);
```

But it alert to me:
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.init (commonService.js:14)
    at new  (loginController.js:8)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4182)
    at $get.extend.instance (angular.js:8441)
    at angular.js:7693
    at forEach (angular.js:331)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:7692)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7075)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:6954)
    at angular.js:1451
angular.js:9814 GET http://localhost:41251/Resources/Chinese.json 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way the error you are getting, simply says that the path to Chinese.json
is wrong, try to open it in a different tab and it will give you same 404. so provide the correct path to the json file.
I haven't used angular translate, but from there examples it seems  you are using it in the wrong way.
basically a provider is only available during the config phase not after that.
From AngularJs site

> During application bootstrap, before Angular goes off creating all
>   services, it configures and instantiates all providers. We call this
>   the configuration phase of the application life-cycle. During this
>   phase, services aren't accessible because they haven't been created
>   yet.
>
> Once the configuration phase is over, interaction with providers is
>   disallowed and the process of creating services starts. We call this
>   part of the application life-cycle the run phase.

you need to set the preferred language and translations during the config phase,
and you can switch the language in your application using the $translate service
use method.  the code below is from the link http://angular-translate.github.io/
Also they have given step by step documentation here http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/07_multi-language
for async loading the example can be found here http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial',     'ngResource', 'pascalprecht.translate']);

myAppModule.config(function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    HEADLINE: 'Hello there, This is my awesome app!',
    INTRO_TEXT: 'And it has i18n support!'
  });
  $translateProvider.translations('de', {
     HEADLINE: 'Hey, das ist meine großartige App!',
     INTRO_TEXT: 'Und sie untersützt mehrere Sprachen!'
  });
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});

myAppModule.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $translate) {
  //key is 'en','de' i.e. the language you
  //you want to use
  $scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
    $translate.use(key);
  };
});
```